# Does OS X support 3x scaling yet?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, graphics, retina-display

In Xcode 6.1 I'm seeing a "3x" and "All" resolutions available for my Mac OS X target. I wonder if the "3x" option is used for Mac apps? If it does, which configurations that calls for the 3x artworks?

[image]

Does the new 5K iMac makes use of those 3x artwork resolutions? Or some Mac pro configurations?

If those 3x artworks are not present, does it render the PDF version instead of upscaling the 2x ones?

Comment: Yeah.. good one. Was wondering myself - didn't get a chance to check out all the last WWDC session videos yet, I suppose the answer's somewhere in there.

Comment: @jay May not be since the 5K iMac wasn't announced in the last WWDC. The same as those 3x resolutions were not available before iPhone 6 Plus was announced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason 3x is available is because in the `Devices` attribute, you've chosen `Universal` – if you choose `Device Specific` and check only `Mac`, you'll see only 1x and 2x.

The 5K iMac just uses 2560x1440 @2x (hence 5120x2800 pixels), not 3x in any case. iPhone 6 Plus is the only device to make use of 3x images, as far as I know.

*Answer accurate at time of writing! (17/04/15)*